# PHP+MySQL Update TimeStamp and get NOW() back

Tags: php, mysql

Is it possible to merge these two mysql queries into one? I want to get NOW() returned to a php variable.

```
mysql_query('INSERT INTO translate (IDRef, RefType, Lang, Text, LastChangeTS) VALUES ('.$id.', \''.$reftype.'\', \''.$lang.'\', \''.$text.'\', NOW()) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE text = \''.$text.'\', LastChangeTS = NOW()');

mysql_query('SELECT LastChangeTS FROM translate WHERE IDRef = '.$id.' AND RefType = \''.$reftype.'\' AND Lang = \''.$lang.'\'');
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't merge a insert statement and a select statement. But, you can sure use a stored procedure which inserts the data and then returns the `LastChange` value.